# select distinct pair values mysql

Tags: mysql

i have the following table and I'm hoping to extract all the unique pairs for ex:

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    1 |    6 |
|    1 |    9 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    3 |    1 |
|    3 |    2 |
|    4 |    1 |
|    6 |    5 |
+------+------+
```

the out put should be

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    1 |    6 |
|    1 |    9 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    6 |    5 |
+------+------+
```

Comment: if the columns and the order doesn't matter `select distinct least(a,b), greatest(a,b) from test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select least(a, b) as a, greatest(a, b) as b
from table t
group by least(a, b), greatest(a, b);
```

This could produce output that is not in the original table (such as 5/6 instead of 6/5).  If you want to preserve the original order:

```
select distinct a, b
from table t
where a <= b or
      not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.b = t.a and t2.a = t.b);
```

That is, select all pairs where `a` is less than or equal to `b` or `a` is greater than `b` and no row exists with the values in the other order.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   a,b
FROM     tbl //your tableName
GROUP BY a,b
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

try this my friend

Comment: @Gordon it does happen to be a low-value code-only solution dump though.  Maybe that was why it was downvoted -- we won't know.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     NAMES2
GROUP BY Id,id2
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1;
```

How about this ?

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.